# Нужна ли запятая после слова "понимают"?

Tags: пунктуация

Сложно здесь с английским языком: местные жители хотели бы помочь иностранцу, но не понимают ни слова.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не требуется. "Ни слова" - обычное дополнение. Отмечу, что обособление стоит под большим вопросом даже при авторской пунктуации, так как теряется смысл.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, так как "ни слова" - дополнение, а дополнения не обособляются.